# List of lists that contain nan or inf in some of their items

Tags: python, math, nan

I have a list in Python that looks as follows:

```
l = [[1,2,inf,inf,87],[3,4,3,5,3],[73,5,3,3,nan],[8,3,3,2,2],[3,3,2,2,inf]]
```

How can I remove those lists that contain `inf` or `nan`?

Thanks.

Comment: Funny thing is none of the linked question help the OP. Find the suitable dupe before closing.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: There is no "in a way duplicate for me". Please read the official [duplicate policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/162455). "If it's only a matter of changing some numerical values or some variable names, they're duplicates. If understanding why the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions aren't duplicates, merely related."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for simple condition i.e

```
import math
l = [[1,2,math.inf,math.inf,87],[3,4,3,5,3],[73,5,3,3,math.nan],[8,3,3,2,2],[3,3,2,2,math.inf]]

[ i for i in l if (math.inf not in i) and (math.nan not in i) ]

[[3, 4, 3, 5, 3], [8, 3, 3, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Note that (while not required by OP) this solution will not catch `-inf`. Perfectly valid approach though.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I got the following when trying your solution: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inf'"

Comment: I simply used float('inf') and float('nan') and think it worked

Comment: Note that `math.nan not in i` only checks for *that* particular `nan` (by which I mean that particular Python object, not that particular nan bit pattern). It's not a safe way to test for general nans. For example, if you try `math.nan not in [float('nan')]`, you'll get an unexpected answer of `True`. `nan` is not a singleton in Python.

Answer (score 4):

```
[subl for subl in l if all(math.isfinite(x) for x in subl)]
```

(given Python >= 3.2; in earlier Pythons, replace with `numpy.isfinite`, or an explicit check for values)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Can you kindly clarify your point "or an explicit check for values"? Especially that I only have "inf" and "nan", and not like "math.inf"?

Comment: `math.inf` is the code that produces the value which displays as `inf`. It does not matter how you get the value itself (`math.inf`, `float('inf')`...), it is the same value.  And by "explicit check for values" I meant something like @Dark is doing.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on @Amadan's answer:

```
list(filter(lambda x: all(map(math.isfinite, x)), l))
```

A more versatile version would use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
list(filter(lambda x: all(map(np.isfinite, x)), l))
```

Answer (score 0):

With inf is math.inf and nan as np.nan:

```
import math
lst = [[1,2,math.inf,math.inf,87],[3,4,3,5,3],[73,5,3,3,np.nan],[8,3,3,2,2],[3,3,2,2,math.inf]]
for l1 in lst:
    if math.inf not in l1 and np.nan not in l1:
        print(l1)
```